# Draw a vertical line at every 15 minute interval on a 1-minute chart

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm trying to draw a vertical line at every 15 minute, example: 08:00, 08:15, 08:30 ....

The following code doesn't output any error but i need you guys to see why there is no lines in chart, please test it

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="15 Minute Lines", shorttitle="15 Minute Lines", overlay=true)

LineLengthMult = 1000
LineLength = ta.atr(100) * LineLengthMult

minutesInPeriod = input.int(15, "Period Length (Minutes)")
periodsInHour = 60 / minutesInPeriod
periodsInDay = periodsInHour * 24
periodStartMinute = input.int(0, "Period Start Minute (0-59)", minval=0, maxval=59)

isPeriodStart = (hour * periodsInHour + math.round((minute - periodStartMinute) / minutesInPeriod)) % periodsInDay == 0

drawVerticalLine(colorr) =>
    line.new(bar_index, low-LineLength, bar_index, high+LineLength, color=colorr, style = line.style_dotted,width=1)

if isPeriodStart
    drawVerticalLine(color.new(color.yellow, 30))
```

I have specified the code, the desired behavior is to display a simple vertical line at every 15 minutes of the clock.

Result: no vertical lines.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code :

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="15 Minute Lines", shorttitle="15 Minute Lines", overlay=true)

minutesInPeriod = input.int(15, "Period Length (Minutes)")
periodStartMinute = input.int(0, "Period Start Minute (0-59)", minval=0, maxval=59)

if minute % minutesInPeriod == periodStartMinute
    line.new(bar_index, close*2, bar_index, close, extend = extend.both, color=color.new(color.blue, 0), style = line.style_dotted,width=1)
```

And get this type of result :
[image]